Error: The plugin "google_maps_flutter_ios" requires a higher minimum iOS deployment version than your application is targeting?
After update to google_maps_flutter: ^2.6.1
I got this error:

Error: The plugin "google_maps_flutter_ios" requires a higher minimum
iOS deployment version than your application is targeting.


replace
platform :ios, '12.0'
with 
platform :ios, '14.0'

& change deployment target to 14.0


